# Currently learning svelte and need some assistance

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

Currently I am trying to create a hacker news clone (not from the example given on website). Currently I made an api call that returns an array but I can't seem to get rid of the square brackets. For reference my code is below

```js
onMount(() => {
    fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty&limitToFirst=10&orderBy="$key"')
        .then((res) => {
            return res.text();
        })
        .then((text) => {
            items = text.split(",");
            setTimeout(3000);
            data = items.filter((val) => {
                return val.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, "");
            });
        });
    //console.log(data);
    //getData(items).then(console.log);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Sadly, your question lacks a lot of info. What "square brackets" exist that your are trying to remove? Show an example of the source data, the data you expect after your code transforms it, and the data output that your code returns now. Review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for info on what goes into a good question because a good question is a question you are more likely to get an answer for. Lastly, indenting your code makes your code _much_ easier to understand for us and for you. Try putting your code in https://beautifier.io/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `setTimeout` is callback-based and will do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API provides a JSON object, but you read it as text (`res.text()`). Replace this with `res.json()` and the result will automatically be parsed to an array of IDs.

There is no need to manipulate JSON in string form, just parse it/let it be parsed.